# identify a procedure and replace it with a different procedure

Tags: perl

What I want to achieve:

```
###############CODE########
old_procedure(arg1, arg2);
#############CODE_END######
```

I have a huge code which has a old procedure in it. I want that the call to that old_procedure go to a call to a new procedure (new_procedure(arg1, arg2)) with the same arguments.
Now I know, the question seems pretty stupid but the trick is I am not allowed to change the code or the bad_function. So the only thing I can do it create a procedure externally which reads the code flow or something and then whenever it finds the bad_function, it replaces it with the new_function. They have a void type, so don't have to worry about the return values.
I am usng perl. If someone knows how to atleast start in this direction...please comment or answer. It would be nice if the new code can be done in perl or C, but other known languages are good too. C++, java.

EDIT: The code is written in shell script and perl. I cannot edit the code and I don't have location of the old_function, I mean I can find it...but its really tough. So I can use the package thing pointed out but if there is a way around it...so that I could parse the thread with that function and replace function calls. Please don't remove tags as I need suggestions from java, C++ experts also.

EDIT: @mirod
So I tried it out and your answer made a new subroutine and now there is no way of accessing the old one. I had created an variable which checks the value to decide which way to go( old_sub or new_sub)...is there a way to add the variable in the new code...which sends the control back to old_function if it is not set...
like:

```
use BadPackage; # sub is defined there
BEGIN
{ package BapPackage;
  no warnings; # to avoid the "Subroutine bad_sub redefined" message
# check for the variable and send to old_sub if the var is not set
  sub bad_sub
    { # good code
    }
}
# Thanks @mirod
```

Comment: In which language is your application written? Also, why do you think a web server language like PHP could solve this in a desktop application (since you never specified where your application executes, we can't be sure of this)?

Comment: Why can't you change the code? You could overwrite old_procedure in the Global offset table, maybe.

Comment: I don't understand what language the code that needs to be changed is written in. I also don't understand how you are going to change the code if you are not allowed to change the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easier to do in Perl than in a lot of other languages, but that doesn't mean it's easy, and I don't know if it's what you want to hear. Here's a proof-of-concept:

Let's take some broken code:

```
# file name: Some/Package.pm
package Some::Package;
use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw(forty_two nineteen);
sub forty_two { 19 }
sub nineteen { 19 }
1;

# file name: main.pl
use Some::Package;
print "forty-two plus nineteen is ", forty_two() + nineteen();
```

Running the program `perl main.pl` produces the output:

```
forty-two plus nineteen is 38
```

It is given that the files `Some/Package.pm` and `main.pl` are broken and immutable. How can we fix their behavior?

One way we can insert arbitrary code to a `perl` command is with the `-M` command-line switch. Let's make a repair module:

```
# file: MyRepairs.pm
CHECK {
    no warnings 'redefine';  
    *forty_two = *Some::Package::forty_two = sub { 42 };
};
1;
```

Now running the program `perl -MMyRepairs main.pl` produces:

```
forty-two plus nineteen is 61
```

Our repair module uses a `CHECK` block to execute code in between the compile-time and run-time phase. We want our code to be the last code run at compile-time so it will overwrite some functions that have already been loaded. The `-M` command-line switch will run our code first, so the `CHECK` block delays execution of our repairs until all the other compile time code is run. See [`perlmod`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlmod) for more details.

This solution is fragile. It can't do much about modules loaded at run-time (with `require ...` or `eval "use ..."` (these are common) or subroutines defined in other `CHECK` blocks (these are rare).

If we assume the shell script that runs `main.pl` is also immutable (i.e., we're not allowed to change `perl main.pl` to `perl -MMyRepairs main.pl`), then we move up one level and pass the `-MMyRepairs` in the `PERL5OPT` environment variable:

```
PERL5OPT="-I/path/to/MyRepairs -MMyRepairs" bash the_immutable_script_that_calls_main_pl.sh
```

Comment: that looks good again...but what can I do if i don't know the package where the old_sub resides...its been an hour and I havn't found it...so I am looking for parsing options

Comment: `grep -d recurse "sub old_sub" $(perl -e 'print "@INC"')` ?

Answer (score 1):

These are called automated refactoring tools and are common for other languages. For Perl though you may well be in a really bad way because parsing Perl to find all the references is going to be virtually impossible.

Comment: I can use other languages...please provide with some resources and some explanation so I can understand clearly what you mean

Answer (score 1):

Where is the old procedure defined?

If it is defined in a package, you can switch to the package, after it has been `use`d, and redefine the sub:

```
use BadPackage; # sub is defined there
BEGIN
{ package BapPackage;
  no warnings; # to avoid the "Subroutine bad_sub redefined" message
  sub bad_sub
    { # good code
    }
}
```

If the code is in the same package but in a different file (loaded through a `require`), you can do the same thing without having to switch package.

if all the code is in the same file, then change it.

Comment: So is the function in a package or not? Also, it is not clear what you CAN do. Can you change the code at all?

Comment: i hope so...i don't even know which language the function is written in...all i know is that i need to parse the process of code and change that function to a new one...As I said I might be able to find the function...then your way could help...but as of now I can't find it

Comment: I cannot change the code...because sometimes I need to run the code with the old function...so I need to create an application which controls the process path and where ever it sees the old_function it calls the new one instead

Answer (score 0):

sed -i 's/old_procedure/new_procedure/g codefile

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Pretty sure that a simple regex is not going to cut parsing Perl.

Comment: no...i have stated in my question that i cannot change the code or the old function...